# Return a message dialog if ID does not exist in database

Tags: java, sqlite, select, null

I have trouble getting my frontend to return a JOptionPane saying the ID does not exist if the user queries an ID that does not exist in my SQLite database and display the records for the ID if it exists. I tried isEmpty() which is apparently incorrect.

My code:

```
        String SelectRecords = "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ID_Num = ?";
        String ID_Number = id_input.getText();
        PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(SelectRecords);
        ps.setString(1, ID_Number);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
           String IDNum = rs.getString("ID_Num");
           String LastName = rs.getString("Stud_Name_Last");
           String FirstName = rs.getString("Stud_Name_First");
           String DaysPresent = rs.getString("days_present");
           String DaysAbsent = rs.getString("days_absent");
           String DropStatus = rs.getString("drop_status");
           String Course = rs.getString("course");
           String LastAttended = rs.getString("last_attended_class");


           String StudentRecords = "ID Number: "+IDNum+"\n"+"Last Name"+LastName+"\n"+"First Name: "+FirstName+"\n"+"Days Present: "+DaysPresent+"\n"+"Days Absent: "+DaysAbsent+"\n"+"Drop Status: "+DropStatus+"\n"+"Course: "+Course+"\n"+"Last Attended On: "+LastAttended;

           Output_Label.setText(LastName+", "+FirstName+"(Retrieving...)");



           if(rs.next() == true){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, StudentRecords, LastName+", "+FirstName, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


           }
           else{
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Does not exist");
           }
```

Comment: `if(IDNum == null) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Does not exist");`

Comment: @juergend Dialog pops if id exists but nothing happens in response to a query for an id that does not exist.

Comment: set a breakpoint in your IDE, look at the value of `idnum` at runtime and you will see what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `rs.next()` twice, which makes sense only if there might be at least two records.
Assuming that there can be only one student with a specific ID, the `while` loop does not make sense either.

The logic of your program should probably look like this:

```
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    // found
} else {
    // not found
}
```